# can't find the null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to create an object of a "Company" using the appropriate facade and I'm getting a null pointer exception that I can't explain.
I tried initializing the attributes with a new arrayList and it didn't seem to work

the facade with the problematic method:

```
package com.lukman.vehicle.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.lukman.vehicle.beans.Company;
import com.lukman.vehicle.beans.Driver;
import com.lukman.vehicle.beans.SafetyOff;
import com.lukman.vehicle.beans.Supervisor;
import com.lukman.vehicle.exceptions.InvalidDetailsException;

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class SupervisorService extends ClientService {
    private int supervisorId;

    public SupervisorService() {
        super();
    }

    public SupervisorService(int supervisorId) {
        super();
        this.supervisorId = supervisorId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean login(String userName, String password) throws InvalidDetailsException {
        List<Supervisor> supervisors = supervisorRepo.findAll();
        for (Supervisor supervisor : supervisors) {
            if (supervisor.getUserName().equals(userName) && supervisor.getPassowrd().equals(password)) {
                this.supervisorId = supervisor.getId();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addCompany(Company company) throws InvalidDetailsException {
        List<Company> companies = companyRepo.findAll();
        for (Company company2 : companies) {
            if (company2.getName().equals(company.getName())) {
                throw new InvalidDetailsException("a company with the same name already exists");
            }
        }
        company.setSupervisorId(this.supervisorId);
        ***companyRepo.save(company);***
    }

    public void updateCompany(Company company) {
        companyRepo.saveAndFlush(company);
    }

    public void deleteCompany(int companyId) {
        companyRepo.delete(companyRepo.getOne(companyId));
    }

    public Company getOneCompany(int companyId) {
        return companyRepo.getOne(companyId);
    }

    public List<Company> getAllCompanies() {
        return companyRepo.findCompaniesBySupervisorId(this.supervisorId);
    }

    public void addDriver(Driver driver) throws InvalidDetailsException {
        List<Driver> drivers = driverRepo.findAll();
        for (Driver driver2 : drivers) {
            if (driver.getTz() == driver2.getTz() || driver.getCompanyId() == 0) {
                throw new InvalidDetailsException("tz must be unique, cannot add driver without specifying companyId");
            }
        }
        driverRepo.save(driver);
    }

    public void deleteDriver(int driverId) {
        driverRepo.delete(driverRepo.getOne(driverId));
    }

    public void addSafetyOff(SafetyOff safetyOff) throws InvalidDetailsException {
        List<SafetyOff> safetyOffs = safetyOffRepo.findAll();
        for (SafetyOff safetyOff2 : safetyOffs) {
            if (safetyOff.getTz() == safetyOff2.getTz()) {
                throw new InvalidDetailsException("tz must be unique");
            }
        }
        safetyOff.setSupervisorId(supervisorId);
        safetyOffRepo.save(safetyOff);
    }

    public void updateSafetyOff(SafetyOff safetyOff) {
        safetyOffRepo.saveAndFlush(safetyOff);
    }

    public void deleteSafetyOff(int safteyOffId) {
        safetyOffRepo.delete(safetyOffRepo.getOne(safteyOffId));
    }
}
```

the Company bean:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Company {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private int id;
    private int supervisorId;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<SafetyOff> safetyOffs = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST }, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "companyId")
    private List<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Company(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
```

the console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.lukman.vehicle.VehicleApplication.main(VehicleApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.lukman.vehicle.service.SupervisorService.addCompany(SupervisorService.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.lukman.vehicle.clr.SupervisorTesting.run(SupervisorTesting.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

the clr:

```
@Order(2)
@Component
@Lazy
public class SupervisorTesting implements CommandLineRunner {

    SupervisorService supervisorService = new SupervisorService(1);

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Company c1 = new Company("coca-cola");
        supervisorService.addCompany(c1);
        c1 = supervisorService.getOneCompany(1);
        c1.setName("cola-coca");
        supervisorService.updateCompany(c1);
```

The parent class:

```
package com.lukman.vehicle.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.lukman.vehicle.exceptions.InvalidDetailsException;
import com.lukman.vehicle.repository.CompanyRepo;
import com.lukman.vehicle.repository.DriverRepo;
import com.lukman.vehicle.repository.SafetyOffRepo;
import com.lukman.vehicle.repository.SubDriverRepo;
import com.lukman.vehicle.repository.SupervisorRepo;

@Service
public abstract class ClientService {
    @Autowired
    protected CompanyRepo companyRepo;
    @Autowired
    protected DriverRepo driverRepo;
    @Autowired
    protected SafetyOffRepo safetyOffRepo;
    @Autowired
    protected SubDriverRepo subDriverRepo;
    @Autowired
    protected SupervisorRepo supervisorRepo;

    public abstract boolean login(String userName, String password) throws InvalidDetailsException;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full source code of SupervisorService and its parent ?

Comment: And please mark line 48 of SupervisorService.

Comment: But with a wild guess i would assume, it's because you create the instance of SupervisorService yourself in SupervisorTesting, instead of having it injected by Spring, and thus the instance is not handled by Spring, which means any fields in ClientService, which should be autowired, might be null.

Comment: Indeed, here is your problem: SupervisorService supervisorService = new SupervisorService(1); This is not managed by Spring, so none of your @Autowired variables will actually be autowired, and remain null

Comment: @ZakiPetrov I added what you asked  and marked line 48 in supervisorService with ***

Comment: @Stultuske i'll give it a go

Comment: @Stultuske worked perfectly thank you so much!